# Winform Application can't startup due to System.Security.SecurityException

Tags: c#, winforms

My Windows Form Application NOT starting due to System.Security.SecurityException.
Here is code on Program.cs

```
 [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new BaseForm());
    }
```

Stacktrace as below.

```
StackTrace:
       System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
       System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
       System.Windows.Forms.Application.add_ThreadException(ThreadExceptionEventHandler value)
       MyApp._0.Program.Main()
```

I have no idea to solving this... Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: whats in your forms startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was struggling a lot on passing this *security exception*. Read loads of blogs, involved in discussions but nothing worked out.

Finally found '**Enable ClickOnce Security Settings**' in msdn. I just followed those steps and disabled the Security Setting in Project properties.

Here is a link hope this helps some: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1sfbfyk0.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Solving by myself.

checking my_project **app.config**, appended unknown security policy settings as below.

```
<runtime>
   <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
</runtime>
<system.web>
<membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
</system.web>
```

**Erased ALL**, then winform application startup on Visual Studio debug mode.